# Android Sqlite Select particular record

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm doing some experiment with Android Sqlite. So basically, I'm doing an app which lets users type in some sentences and the app should display the ambiguous words (i.e. words that have multiple meanings). I have a table tblWords (fields are: _id, words, meanings)
In each word, there are two meanings like **break**

For example:

***TblWords*** 
_id     words     meanings 
1     BREAK     Some abrupt occurrence that interrupts an ongoing activity 
2     BREAK     A pause from doing something (as work)

etc...

What I want to do, I want the app to display the only the first records on some certain conditions, otherwise display the second record. How can I achieve something like this? I really need ideas to get me started with. Any help is truly appreciated. And give also some points to consider. Thanks again.

**UPDATE:**

This is what I've tried so far,

**DBHelper.class**

```
  public Cursor getAllWords()
{ 
            return this.myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
                    KEY_ID, KEY_WORD, KEY_MEANING }, null, null, null, null, null);

}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
ArrayList<String> colWords = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> colMeanings = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] words;
String[] meanings;

    cursor = dbHelper.getAllWords();

    colWords.clear();///added code
    colMeanings.clear();///added code


    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                colWords.add(cursor.getString(1)); 
                colMeanings.add(cursor.getString(2));   
                String records = cursor.getString(0);

                Log.d("Records", records);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

get 2 records and check the condition if true show first record otherwise in else display the second record

Comment: Can you give me some sample codes to be able to start implementing it?

Comment: sure! 
https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=gmail&attid=0.1&thid=13efe457cb10e99d&mt=application/rar&url=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui%3D2%26ik%3D156b3e471a%26view%3Datt%26th%3D13efe457cb10e99d%26attid%3D0.1%26disp%3Dsafe%26realattid%3Df_hhedmdrs0%26zw&sig=AHIEtbTBV38wDUX-OA-7GP2AzKoVZuY8QQ
check if you can download it?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/18JzpDFvyps-G0B8WeAXShb3PHI-adirJhGZuYS2gq5V9LJaM7l27xHTx73z3/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay. I requested access to your file.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @AlG I have already answered the question he demanded sample code so I shared my code with him. BTW thanks for the advise

Comment: @MuhammadAliHassan I am sure you have. However, the next person to come through in days, months, or years, may not be able to get to that link. Having the example here helps future visitors, not just the OP.

Comment: @MuhammadAliHassan I cannot access your file again.

Comment: @Dunkey click this
[link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/18JzpDFvyps-G0B8WeAXShb3PHI-adirJhGZuYS2gq5V9LJaM7l27xHTx73z3/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @MuhammadAliHassan Hi I viewed your files but I don't think it will help my specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add another column, say `definition_number` so that your table looks like the following:

**_id**  **word**  **definition_number**  **meaning**

1 BREAK 1 *first definition for break*

2 BREAK 2 *second definition for break*

3 CONTINUE 1 *first definition for continue*

4 CONTINUE 2 *second definition for continue*

Now if you want all the first definitions do

```
this.myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_WORD, KEY_MEANING}, 
       "defintion_number = 1", null, null, null, null)
```

and if you want all the second definitions do

```
this.myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_WORD, KEY_MEANING}, 
       "defintion_number = 2", null, null, null, null)
```

I'll add, even though it doesn't address your problem, that you might want to consider separating your data into two tables, *Words* and *Definitions*, and then joining as appropriate. Since this is tangential, I won't go into detail, but do a search for *schema normalization* for more information on why you would want to do this.

Comment: thanks I've never thought about doing this. My question about the conditions, how can I apply it? I mean, there are words that need to print the first definition else print the second one.

Comment: Well if every word is going to have different constraints, than it gets trickier, but you can always build a where clause that makes use of more constraints. If you could give more details on how you choose which definition to display, I might be able to put together a better sample answer.

Comment: Actually, I need to get the context of the sentence. Like if the ambiguous word has matched the 1st word from the table then print 1st meaning otherwise print the second meaning.